# Find if disk space is available before creating VM using ESX shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, esx

I have two storage disks on a ESX host with the names `data` and `data1`.

If i do a `df -h|grep -E 'data'` on an ESX shell it gives the disk size of both the storage disks. Is there a grep command in ESX shell command for exact word match?

Note `grep -w` does not exist for ESX shell. 
Please help.

Comment: Is `grep -v` exist in the ESX shell?

Comment: Show how output of `df -h` looks like. Try to use `'data '` or `'data$'`

Comment: grep -v does exist. I figured it out. df  -m|grep -E 'data'|grep -v 'data1'